# Memory usage by Array of Long, Array of Integer and ArrayList

Tags: java, memory

Whether I use `Long[]`, `Integer[]` or `ArrayList<Integer>`, why do all of them return the same memory usage?

```
System.out.println("Memory Usage : " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024));
System.out.println("Memory Usage : " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1024*1024));

//Long[] aa = new Long[70000000];
Integer[] bb = new Integer[70000000];
//ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(70000000);

System.gc();

System.out.println("Memory Usage : " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/(1024*1024));
System.out.println("Memory Usage : " + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/(1024*1024));
```

Comment: Because your measurement methods are completely inaccurate.  `System.gc()` is "Hey, can you maybe GC at some point in the vaguely near future?" and `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` is a very rough approximation that can be wildly off.

Comment: What's this got to do with Spring and Hibernate?

Answer (score 6):

> In the above statements Whether i use Long[], Integer[] or ArrayList, why all of them give same memory usage ?

It makes perfect sense. In all cases, you're basically allocating an array which is 70000000 * (size of reference on your JVM). The size of an `Integer` reference is the same as the size of a `Long` reference, which is the same as the size of an `Object` reference. In the `ArrayList` case you've got the very small additional overhead of the `ArrayList` object itself, but that's pretty small - and easily explained as per Louis's comment.

If you actually *populated* those arrays, creating *instances* of `Long` and `Integer`, *then* you'd see a difference. Likewise if you created a `long[]` vs an `int[]`, you'd see a difference.